# HAProxy hour, day, week logging

Tags: haproxy

Is there a way I can get similar stats to WebAlizer from HAProxy so I can see the amount of traffic - historically - which hits my HAProxy server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HAProxy is load balancer that can generate web logs. Webalizer, AWStats, etc parse the log files and generate the reports.

Therefore there are two routes you can take:

1. See if your web analyzer supports a custom log format parsing option and adjust the analysis program to fit haproxy logs. Usually this will be some sort of regular expression configuration directive.
2. Customize haproxy logs to fit what your log analysis program expects

HAProxy does support the common log format (CLF) via the `option httplog clf` directive ([see documentation](http://code.google.com/p/haproxy-docs/wiki/httplog)).  HAProxy also recently supports custom logs formats, [see the 1.5 documentation section 8.2.4](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.5/doc/configuration.txt).

Between these two options one or combination of the two should be able to get you where you want to go.